# Angular @Unsubscribe decorator for @Component

Tags: angular, rxjs

*You probably all know that you need to unsubscribe from **Observables** to prevent memory leaks*.

I don't understand why not just create **@Uncsubscribe** decorator for component class where you use Observables and it will go through all the properties and unsubscribe all the subscriptions on *destroy*.

Or even more sugar: extend **@Component** decorator to add such behaviour.

and now **Question**: What could be the pitfalls of this solution?

Comment: _why not just create @Uncsubscribe decorator_ - how? can you show?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is a good article about [this](https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-auto-unsubscribe).

Here's the overview

```
@AutoUnsubscribe(["one$", "two$"])
class TestComponent {
  ...
}
```

Where one$ and two$ are your observables and it will automatically be unsubscribed in NgOnDestroy

If you are using AOT, make sure that you add the NgOnDestroy in your component. See [this](https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-auto-unsubscribe)

Comment: Are you sure that angular will run `ngOnDestroy` method in aot compilation if we didn't declare it directly? AOT is always problem for us. So what is the difference between having one `takeUntil` and such implementation. In both cases we have to declare `ngOnDestroy` hook on component

Comment: @yurzui thank you for pointing that out. I take back that there are no pitfalls on this implementation. Using AOT can be a problem with this implementation. I'll investigate further about this

Comment: Here is the place where it is checked https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/aot/static_reflector.ts#L255-L268

Comment: @yurzui I believe the original author has found a solution for this. https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-auto-unsubscribe. Though I can't test it thoroughly right now.

Comment: See example `// If you work with AOT this method must be present, even if empty! `

Comment: I guess if you are going to use this, you need to declare ngOnDestroy explicitly in your component